# Trouble lining up lubridate x-axes via patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lubridate, patchwork

I am trying to make a sampling schematic that shows the samples that were collected at each time point during a field campaign, as related to the tidal cycle. Originally, I made the tidal cycle graphs in R, and then made the sampling boxes below in PowerPoint, but I've been trying to make a reproducible version of the entire figure in R. However, I am having trouble getting the two sections of the graph to properly align with patchwork.

The boxes in the bottom of the schematic should be centered underneath the times on the x axis, as shown here (in the version I made by hand):
[Sampling schematic made by hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UizVL.png)

However, when I create the figure in R, the first column of yellow boxes is perfectly positioned, but then they become increasingly offset, even though the x axes of the two panels should be the same (as set via coord_cartesian): [Sampling schematic made in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nPVm.png)

I'm sure it's something small/silly that's messing up the alignment on the far side of the chart, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Code used is below, which requires two data files. [28-Jan-2022-TideChart.txt](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/files/12074519/28-Jan-2022-TideChart.txt) is used in this first chunk:

```
#Read Pillar Point NOAA/NOS/CO-OPs Tide Chart data file
Tides = read.table("Data/28-Jan-2022-TideChart.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", dec = ".", skip=13)

#Convert date format in table using lubridate
Tides$datetime <- lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(Tides$Date, Tides$Time), tz = "US/Pacific")

#Set bounds of sampling period to highlight
xmin = Tides$datetime[47]
xmax = Tides$datetime[69]
ymin = -.5
ymax = .5

box_color = "#EDEDED"

#Create plot of full tidal cycle with sampling period highlighted
p1 <- ggplot(data=Tides, aes(x=datetime, y = Pred, group=1)) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = box_color) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(Tides$datetime[1], Tides$datetime[96])) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA_character_), 
    # necessary to avoid drawing panel outline
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA_character_),
    # necessary to avoid drawing plot outline
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, linewidth=1)
  ) +
  xlab("Time (PST)") +
  ylab("MLLW Tide Prediction (m)") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hour", date_labels = "%H:00", expand = c(0, 0), position = "top")

#Create plot of just sampling period
p2 <- ggplot(data=Tides, aes(x=datetime, y = Pred, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xmin, xmax), ylim = c(ymin, ymax)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = box_color), 
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA_character_), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, linewidth=1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("MLLW Tide Prediction (m)") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "30 min", date_labels = "%H:%M", expand = c(0, 0))

#Stitch plots together using patchwork
p_patch <- p1 / p2 & ylab(NULL) & theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 0), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA_character_))

# Use the tag label as a y-axis label
p_patch = wrap_elements(p_patch) +
  labs(tag = "MLLW Tide Prediction (m)") +
  theme(
    plot.tag = element_text(size = rel(1.2), angle = 90),
    plot.tag.position = "left",
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA_character_)
  )

p_patch
```

And then [Chart_Data.csv](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/files/11971114/Chart_Data.csv) needs to be imported for use as data_forchart here:

```
data_forchart = amp$metadata[!is.na(amp$metadata$Time),]

data_forchart = data_forchart %>% group_by(SiteByTime) %>% mutate(chart_num = ceiling(row_number()/3))

data_forchart$datetime <- lubridate::ymd_hm(paste("2022/01/28", data_forchart$Time), tz = "US/Pacific")
data_forchart$LocNumTime = as.factor(paste(data_forchart$Location, data_forchart$chart_num, data_forchart$Time))


facet.labs =  c("Tide Pool 1\n (S1)", "Tide Pool 2\n (S2)", "Nearshore\n (N)", "Field Blank")
names(facet.labs) = c("S1", "S2", "N", "FB")

data_forchart$Location= factor(data_forchart$Location, levels=c("S1", "S2", "N", "FB"))

sample_schema = ggplot(data = data_forchart, aes(x = Time, y = chart_num, shape = Location,
                                 color = Time, 
                                 fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.05)))) + 
  geom_beeswarm(cex = 2, size = 4) + 
  statebins:::geom_rrect(aes(xmin = after_stat(x) - 0.45, 
                             xmax = after_stat(x) + 0.45,
                             ymin = after_stat(y) - 0.4, 
                             ymax = after_stat(y) + 0.45),
                         radius = unit(3, "pt")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 17, 16, 18)) + 
  scale_color_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  facet_grid(Location ~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", 
             switch = "y", labeller = labeller(Location = facet.labs)) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = .9))  

p_patch/sample_schema
```